# Virtualization is on but still getting the error while installing HAXM

Tags: haxm

The error says that your system supports HAXM but Intel Virtualization Technology is not turned on. But I checked that Virtualization is enabled. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Go into your BIOS setup and enable VT-x.

I was unable to get it installed and ended up installing the [GenyMotion](https://university.xamarin.com/resources/accelerating-android-emulators) Android Emulator. It worked and is fast.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFJYpT7L5ag) is a really good video showing how to enable virtualization in Bios. I'm not sure why, but if you're using the Intel Processor Identification Utility, it says that virtualization is enabled, but that really only indicates that your computer supports virtualization, not that it's actually enabled. Once you've enabled VT-x in the Bios, you should be able to install HAXM and run your emulator much more quickly!